# Async alternative to CsvDataReader?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm trying to use CsvHelper to parse a CSV file and stream it to SQL Database. `CsvDataReader` class seems perfect for that, however it doesn't implement any async methods, which is weird to me, considering that underlying `CsvReader` has async versions of all of its reading methods. Is there a way to use `CsvDataReader` in an asynchronous way?

Comment: CsvDataReader implements IDataReader and so enforces behavior like any other DataReader and those do not have asnyc features (Consider the age of that stuff). If you need async and CsvReader does that then simply use that?

Comment: YMMV, but in tests I did `CsvHelper` was not particularly well optimized anyway (compared to some "dumb" hand written code that didn't handle any complicated quoting scenarios) making it less attractive for bulk load scenarios. It's convenient, but not necessarily fast. Accessing columns of a data readers asynchronously isn't fast either: it consists of lots of small synchronous operations that can really tank perf (no `ValueTask`s either). To a first approximation, unless you're loading lots of files in parallel and need the scaling, asynchrony won't actually improve things.

Comment: Many DBMS have built-in capabilities for importing data from files of different formats. Which DBMS exactly do you use?

Comment: If this is MS SQL Server it can _definitely_ import CSV natively.

Comment: @Fildor yes it can, but I need to add an ability for users to upload CSV files (possibly adding other file types in the future) to the database through the Web API

Comment: @JeroenMostert what solution would you recommend? Dumb hand-written CSV parsing isn't a good fit for my situation, since I do have some quoting scenarios in my case, and I'm receiving the file from the Http request. Also yes, scalability is important for my use-case, because the intended functionality is to allow the users to upload their files to the Web API

Comment: Just any CSV or specific ones that match certain tables? If so, you can write Database scripts and run (trigger start) them from your code.

Comment: @Ralf yes, CsvReader itself has asynchronous features, but it's not (directly) usable by SqlBulkCopy. I can write my own DbDataReader wrapper on CsvReader, but I'm interested whether there are out-the-box solutions

Comment: @Fildor there are minimal requirenments on which columns must be included, but a) there are multiple possible names for any of the columns (e.g. there must be a PartNumber column included, but it can be called "Number", "PartNumber", "PRT_NMBR", etc.), and there could be additional columns, which would be inserted into a separate [CustomAttributes] column

Comment: Nahh, too bad. Could have been so easy...

Comment: "Correcting" the CSV might still be an option and then use the direct bulk capabilities of the SQL server. I don't think there is a DbDataReader ready for CSV. Most people will feel disgusted using the word "DB" in conjunction with "CSV" ;)

Comment: @Ralf if by correct the CSV you mean having a single expected CSV structure - it's not possible. Those CSV may come from different source which I have no control over, and users having the ability to add additional columns to the file is absolutely required

Answer (score 1):

I've used this before to bulk import CSV files using `Entity Framework`. This is using LINQPad so you might need to make a couple of changes.

```cs
async Task Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        MemberTypes = CsvHelper.Configuration.MemberTypes.Fields
    };
    
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\MyBulkFile.csv"))
    using(var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();

        await BulkInsertChunks(records);
    }
}

async Task<int> BulkInsertChunks<T>(IEnumerable<T> entites, int chunkAmount = 10000)
{
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var uploadRecords = new List<T>();
    foreach (var record in entites)
    {
        if (i < chunkAmount - 1)
        {
            i++;
            j++;
            uploadRecords.Add(record);
        }
        else
        {
            i = 0;
            j++;
            uploadRecords.Add(record);
            Console.WriteLine($"Uploading {j}");
            await BulkInsertAll<T>(uploadRecords);
            uploadRecords.Clear();
        }
    }

    $"Uploading {j}".Dump();
    await BulkInsertAll<T>(uploadRecords);

    return j;
}

async Task BulkInsertAll<T>(List<T> entities)
{
    var connstr = Connection.ConnectionString;
    var conn = new SqlConnection(Connection.ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();

    Type t = typeof(T);
    var tableAttribute = (TableAttribute)t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), false).Single();
    var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn) { DestinationTableName = tableAttribute.Name };
    var properties = t.GetMembers().Where(p =>
    {
        var columnAttribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(p, typeof(ColumnAttribute)) as ColumnAttribute;
        if (columnAttribute != null) return true;
        return false;
    }).ToArray();
    var table = new DataTable();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        Type propertyType = ((FieldInfo)property).FieldType;
        if (propertyType.IsGenericType && propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
        {
            propertyType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType);
        }
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(property.Name, propertyType));
    }
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        var cols = properties.Select(property =>
        {
            var field = (FieldInfo)property;
            var o = field.GetValue(entity);
            if (o == null)
                return DBNull.Value;
            else
                return o;
        }).ToArray();
        table.Rows.Add(cols);
    }
    await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(table);
    conn.Close();
}
```